# Monogame game turns white and unresponsive when exiting out of window. How do I fix it?

Tags: c#, windows, monogame

When I try using Alt+Tab, or I minimise my Monogame game the screen turns completely white and doesn't respond, I can't move the window anymore so the only thing I have left to do is to close it manually. Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Never saw this happen with my projects. If you add breakpoints, are you still going through you update and render methods?

Comment: My game works as intended, however if it is ran in fullscreen and I use the Alt+Tab combination, my game will permanently turn white and not respond.